# Yii2: Call to undefined method backend\models\CreateBookings::model()

Tags: php, yii2

Trying to fetch data from db

**in controllers**

```
$model = new CreateBookings();
$data = CreateBookings::model()->findByPk();

    return $this->render('view', [
                'data' => $data,
            ]);
```

in view :

```
<?php echo $data->booking_id?>
```

can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: is your CreateBookings extending model?

Comment: Yes it is extending model

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/26408-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-model/

Comment: yii2 alternative for `findByPk()`? as its from yii 1?

Comment: @Saurabh are you using yii1 or Yii2  ? you need an alternative of  yii1 findByPk in yii2?

Comment: im using yii2, i need alternative for yii2.
the way im obtaining the data, is it right?
I tried `<?php echo ' ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->booking_id; ?>` but it only showing data at index `0`

Comment: I have posted an answer  .. i hope is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative for Yii1  `findByPk` in Yii2 is `findOne($id)`

```
 $model = CreateBookings::findOne($id);
```

or the equivalent

```
 $model = CreateBookings::find()
->where(['id' => $id])
->one();
```

for your view  you can use

```
 $data = CreateBookings::findOne($id)) ;
```

and  you should have the $id value.

Comment: in view im using `<?php echo Html::encode($data->booking_id); ?>` its working though, but is there any better alternative?

Comment: $model  or $data you can change the var name .. and you should have the $id for pk .. i have update the answer ..

Comment: doing my college project

Answer (score 0):

**Answering My own question:**

I wanted to show database values in my View.

In controller `actionView` I added-

```
$data = CreateBookings::findOne($id);
```

and rendered

```
'data' => $data,
```

To show value in view I used

```
<?php echo Html::encode($data->booking_id);?>
```